# Error when I run bitbake

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, yocto, bitbake

I have installed the yocto project and the meta-raspberry layer. When I try to bitbake the image (bitbake rpi-basic-image) I receive these errors:

```
user:~/Desktop/yocto_r/build-rpi$ bitbake rpi-basic-image
Loading cache: 100% |############################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 15 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: /home/user/Desktop/yocto_r/poky/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-core/images/rpi-test-image.bb: Deprecated variable(s) found: "IMAGE_DEPENDS_rpi-sdimg". Use do_image_<type>[depends] += "<recipe>:<task>" instead
ERROR: /home/user/Desktop/yocto_r/poky/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-core/images/rpi-basic-image.bb: Deprecated variable(s) found: "IMAGE_DEPENDS_rpi-sdimg". Use do_image_<type>[depends] += "<recipe>:<task>" instead
ERROR: /home/user/Desktop/yocto_r/poky/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-core/images/rpi-hwup-image.bb: Deprecated variable(s) found: "IMAGE_DEPENDS_rpi-sdimg". Use do_image_<type>[depends] += "<recipe>:<task>" instead
ERROR: Failed to parse recipe: /home//Desktop/yocto_r/poky/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-core/images/rpi-test-image.bb
```

Anyone knows what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the recipe is not compatible with updated image-types class.
Replace IMAGE_DEPENDS_rpi-sdimg by do_image_rpi-sdimg[depends].

For example if you have

```
IMAGE_DEPENDS_rpi-sdimg = "virtual/kernel"
```

then replace it with

```
do_image_rpi-sdimg[depends] += "virtual/kernel:do_populate_sysroot"
```

Answer (score -2):

I also had this problem.
modify meta-raspberrypi/classes/sdcard_image-rpi.bbclass file like below

```
diff --git a/classes/sdcard_image-rpi.bbclass b/classes/sdcard_image-rpi.bbclass
index 79ab53a..91719f2 100644
--- a/classes/sdcard_image-rpi.bbclass
+++ b/classes/sdcard_image-rpi.bbclass
@@ -50,7 +50,7 @@ IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT = "4096"
 SDIMG_ROOTFS_TYPE ?= "ext3"
 SDIMG_ROOTFS = "${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_NAME}.rootfs.${SDIMG_ROOTFS_TYPE}"

-IMAGE_DEPENDS_rpi-sdimg = " \
+do_image_rpi-sdimg = " \
                        parted-native \
                        mtools-native \
                        dosfstools-native \
```